# Load data only when page is scrolled down MVC 4 Jquery Mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

In my view am populating contents taken from a Table which has more than 1000 records. I have to populate the contents in a manner that records are populated to fewer records only when scrolled down and not at once. I use this for developing a mobile application. I have tried with various sources online but not effective to the extent of scrolling. If you are still not clear with my question, most of you might have used facebook. There the posts are not loaded all at once. only when scrolled they are loaded. i have to implement the same functionality. Any references to the realtime code will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Here is my code where i am getting the records

```
@foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.dtSearch.Rows)
{
if (Model.dtSearch.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
    <input type ="hidden" value="@row["ProductId"]" />
    <input type ="hidden" value="@row["ProductPriceId"]" />

    <div class="divSearchResult" id="divSearch">
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td rowspan="2" style="width:10%"> @Html.Raw(row["ThumbnailFilename"])</td>
    <td colspan="3"><div class="divSearchHeader"> @row["ProductName"] <br /></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="4"><div class="divSearchShowHide" ><a class="classShow" id="show" href="#" style="text-decoration:none">Show</a></div>
    <div style="display:none;" class="divSearchContent" id=divresult_@ProductDescription > @Html.Raw(row["ProductDescription"])</div></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr />
</div>

    }}
```

There is no point in showing the code but this is where i must get the functionality implemented

Comment: Google [infinite Scroll][1] . If you are familiar with ajax, then a simple task.
 [1]: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=infinite%20scroll%20jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RustyLazyLoad consists of six main components:

1.rustylazyload.js
2.rustylazyload.css
3.RustyLazyLoadViewModel.cs
4._RustyLazyLoad.cshtml
5.Your Controller lazy load action method and the corresponding ViewModel
6.Your PartialView template

First, we'll quickly run through rustylazyload.js:

```
function LazyLoad(uniqueId) {

var _uniqueId = uniqueId;

var _containerId = "";
var _ajaxLoadContainerId = "";
var _ajaxActionUrl = "";
var _parameters = {};

this.init = function(option) {

    _containerId = option.containerId;
    _ajaxLoadContainerId = option.ajaxLoadContainerId;
    _ajaxActionUrl = option.ajaxActionUrl;
    _parameters = option.parameters;

    // Enable scroll event handler
    bindScrollHandler();

    // Load initial items
    load();
};

var bindScrollHandler = function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
            load();
        }
    });
};

var unbindScrollHandler = function() {
    $(window).unbind("scroll");
};

var load = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: _ajaxActionUrl,
        data: _parameters,
        beforeSend: load_beforeSend,
        success: load_success,
        error: load_error
    });
};

var load_beforeSend = function() {
    // Disable scroll event handler
    unbindScrollHandler();

    // Show loading message
    $(_ajaxLoadContainerId).toggleClass("lazyload-hidden").html("Loading..");
};
var load_success = function(result) {

    // Delay a bit before displaying the result and re-enabling scroll event handler
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Display result with fade in effect
        if (result != null && result != "") {
            $(_containerId).append(result, { duration: 500 });
            // Add ui-first-child to the first child
            $(_containerId).find(">:first-child").removeClass("ui-first-child");
            $(_containerId).find(">:first-child").addClass("ui-first-child");
            // Remove ui-last-child from the old last child
            $(_containerId).find(">:nth-child(" + _parameters.fromRowNumber + ")").removeClass("ui-last-child");
            // Add ui-last-child to the new last child
            $(_containerId).find(">:last-child").addClass("ui-last-child");

            // Update fromRowNumber
            _parameters.fromRowNumber = $(_containerId).children().length;
        }

        if (_parameters.fromRowNumber == 0) {
            // Use loading container to display 'no item' message
            $(_ajaxLoadContainerId).html("There is no data to display");
        } else {
            // Remove loading message
            $(_ajaxLoadContainerId).toggleClass("lazyload-hidden").html("");
        }

        // Re-enable scroll handler
        bindScrollHandler();
    }, 500);

};
var load_error = function(result) {
    var message = result.responseText.substring(1, result.responseText.length - 2);
    $(_ajaxLoadContainerId).html("Error: " + message);
};
}
```

There are 4 mandatory fields that we need to specify when calling init():

_containerId - the Id of the data container object (`<ul id="thisId"></ul>`)
_ajaxLoadContainerId - the Id of the "Loading" message container object (`<div id="thisId">Loading..</div>`)
_ajaxActionUrl - The action Url which will be called using $.ajax() 
_parameters - a JSON object, which has 2 mandatory fields: limit (number of items to be loaded on demand) and fromRowNumber (marks the Nth loaded item to avoid repeated entries).

We won't go and discuss this code above line by line, instead we'll just highlight the important sections:

init() function does three things: maps the parameters, binds scroll event handler to the window, and calls load() to display the first batch
bindScrollHandler() is quite trivial - it simply makes sure load() gets called when the window almost reaches the bottom

load() calls _ajaxActionUrl using jQuery AJAX and passes all specified parameters in _parameters variable - ASP.NET MVC is smart enough to map those parameters with the Controller action parameters

When the Controller action is performing, `load_beforeSend()` temporarily disables the window scroll event handler so we don't overload the server with AJAX requests, meanwhile displays the loading message HTML object which Id is stored in _ajaxLoadContainerId
On success, `load_success()` should bind the result to _containerId HTML object, update the `_parameters.fromRowNumber` with the number of items loaded (remember fromRowNumber is one of the mandatory items of _parameters), and re-enables the window scroll event handler
Any error will be handled in load_error(), which will be displayed in _ajaxLoadContainerId HTML object

If you are using default ASP.NET MVC4 Mobile Application template, you shouldn't need to modify this file at all

Next is rustylazyload.css, which should be quite straight forward:

```
.lazyload-loading-container {
margin: 0;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
}
.lazyload-hidden {
display: none;
 }
```

Now, the View Model RustyLazyLoadViewModel.cs:

```
  using System.Collections.Generic;

  namespace RustyLazyLoadTester.Mobile.Models
  {
public class RustyLazyLoadViewModel
{
    public RustyLazyLoadViewModel()
    {
        Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
    public RustyLazyLoadViewModel(int limit, int fromRowNumber, string containerId,
        string ajaxActionUrl, IDictionary<string, object> parameters = null)
    {
        Limit = limit;
        FromRowNumber = fromRowNumber;
        ContainerId = containerId;
        AjaxActionUrl = ajaxActionUrl;
        if (parameters != null)
            Parameters = parameters;
    }

    public int Limit { get; set; }
    public int FromRowNumber { get; set; }
    public string ContainerId { get; set; }
    public string AjaxActionUrl { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; }
}
}
```

As you can see, this View Model captures pretty much the same parameters as rustylazyload.js' `.init()` function, except without the _ajaxLoadContainerId. Why? Let's check out the View file.

**_RustyLazyLoad.cshtml:**

```
 @using System.Text
 @model RustyLazyLoadTester.Mobile.Models.RustyLazyLoadViewModel
 @{
var containerId = Model.ContainerId;
var ajaxLoadContainerId = string.Format("{0}Load", containerId);

// Convert parameters to JSON
var sbParameters = new StringBuilder();
if (Model.Parameters != null && Model.Parameters.Any())
{
    foreach (var parameter in Model.Parameters)
    {
        sbParameters.AppendFormat("\"{0}\": \"{1}\", ", parameter.Key, parameter.Value);
    }
}
var parameters = sbParameters.ToString();
// Remove trailing ', ' from parameters
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameters))
{
    parameters = parameters.Substring(0, parameters.Length - 2);
}
}
<ul id="@containerId" data-role="listview" 
         data-inset="true"></ul>
<div id="@ajaxLoadContainerId"
 class="lazyload-loading-container lazyload-hidden
        ui-listview ui-listview-inset
        ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-li-static
        ui-btn-down-b ui-first-child ui-last-child"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var limit = @Model.Limit;
    var fromRowNumber = @Model.FromRowNumber;
    var containerId = '@string.Format("#{0}", containerId)';
    var ajaxLoadContainerId = '@string.Format("#{0}", ajaxLoadContainerId)';
    var ajaxActionUrl = '@Model.AjaxActionUrl';
    var parameters = { limit: limit, fromRowNumber: fromRowNumber, @Html.Raw(parameters) };

    var lazyLoad = new LazyLoad(containerId);
    lazyLoad.init({
        containerId: containerId,
        ajaxLoadContainerId: ajaxLoadContainerId,
        ajaxActionUrl: ajaxActionUrl,
        parameters: parameters
    });
});
</script>
```

For simplicity, _ajaxLoadContainerId is really just _containerId with a suffix, but it can be anything, really. Should we feel the need to specify your AJAX loading message container Id manually, all we need to do is add AjaxLoadContainerId as a property in RustyLazyLoadViewModel.cs and pass that on to variable ajaxLoadContainerId (line 5 in this page).

**The lazy load item container is this:**

```
 <ul id="@containerId" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
```

And the lazy load loading message container is this:

```
 <div id="@ajaxLoadContainerId" ...></div>
```

Then using the Razor engine we convert the parameters into a JSON and pass it on to the lazy load control.

```
var parameters = { limit: limit, fromRowNumber: fromRowNumber, @Html.Raw(parameters) };

var lazyLoad = new LazyLoad(containerId);
lazyLoad.init({
containerId: containerId,
ajaxLoadContainerId: ajaxLoadContainerId,
ajaxActionUrl: ajaxActionUrl,
parameters: parameters
});
```

Lastly, the fifth and sixth component are best explained through an example.

Say there are 15 entries of User in the database with these fields: Id, FirstName, LastName, Status and mapped to the model below. and we want to display the entries on the Home page in a progressive manner using the lazy load control.

```
 using System.ComponentModel;

 namespace RustyLazyLoadTester.Mobile.Services.Models
 {
public class User
{
    public User() { }
    public User(long id, string firstName, string lastName, UserStatus status)
        : this()
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Status = status;
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public enum UserStatus
{
    [Description("All")]
    All = 0,
    [Description("Inactive")]
    Inactive = 1,
    [Description("Active")]
    Active = 2,
    [Description("Deactivated")]
    Deactivated = 3
}
}
```

**The first thing we need to do is create the service method:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using RustyLazyLoadTester.Mobile.Services.Models;

namespace RustyLazyLoadTester.Mobile.Services
{
public interface IQueryService
{
    IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers(UserStatus status = UserStatus.All,
                                  int limit = 0, int fromRowNumber = 0);
}

class QueryService : IQueryService
{
    public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers(UserStatus status, int limit, int fromRowNumber)
    {
        // Assume we have 15 users
        var users = new List<User>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            var userFirstName = string.Format("firstName_{0}", i);
            var userLastName = string.Format("lastName_{0}", i);
            var userStatus = i % 2 == 0 ? UserStatus.Active : UserStatus.Inactive;
            users.Add(new User(i, userFirstName, userLastName, userStatus));
        }

        if (limit <= 0)
        {
            users = users.Where(x => x.Status == status)
                        .Skip(fromRowNumber)
                        .ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            users = users.Where(x => x.Status == status)
                        .Skip(fromRowNumber)
                        .Take(limit)
                        .ToList();
        }
        return users;
    }
}
}
```

In our HomeController, we will need to create the default [HttpGet] Controller action method Index() for our Index page and the [HttpPost] Controller action method GetNextUsers() to serve the lazy loader:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RustyLazyLoadTester.Mobile.Services;
using RustyLazyLoadTester.Mobile.Services.Models;

namespace RustyLazyLoadTester.Mobile.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IQueryService _query;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _query = new QueryService();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetNextUsers(UserStatus status, int limit, int fromRowNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            var users = _query.GetAllUsers(status, limit, fromRowNumber);

            if (!users.Any())
                return Json(string.Empty);

            return PartialView("_UserList", users);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            return Json(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

In Index.cshtml (the View corresponding to the [HttpGet] Controller action method Index()) we will have something like this:

```
@using RustyLazyLoadTester
@using RustyLazyLoadTester.Mobile.Models
@using RustyLazyLoadTester.Mobile.Services.Models
@{
ViewBag.PageTitle = "Home";
ViewBag.Title = string.Format("RustyLazyLoadTester - {0}", ViewBag.PageTitle);

var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("status", UserStatus.All);
}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lazyload") @* points to /Scripts/rustylazyload.js *@

@Html.Partial("_RustyLazyLoad", new RustyLazyLoadViewModel(
5, 0, "ulUsers", Url.Action("GetNextUsers", "Home"), parameters))
```

The two bolded lines there will activate the lazy load control and trigger the GetNextUsers() on demand.

If we look closely on the second bolded line:

```
@Html.Partial("_RustyLazyLoad", new RustyLazyLoadViewModel(
5, 0, "ulUsers", Url.Action("GetNextUsers", "Home"), parameters))
```

The value 5 is the limit. This dictates how the number of items to be retrieved on each load. The value 0 is the fromRowNumber. This represents the N-th item in the result that needs to be ignored. As we load more data, this number will increase based on the loaded items, so we don't have to worry about duplicates (unless our code involves some complex sorting which makes it possible to have a new item in the middle of the list).

When GetNextUsers() method is called, it simply renders PartialView _UserList.cshtml below:

```
@using Humanizer
@using RustyLazyLoadTester.Mobile.Services.Models
@model IEnumerable<User>

@foreach (var user in Model)
{ 
<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-b">
    <div>@string.Format("First name: {0}", user.FirstName)</div>
    <div>@string.Format("Last name: {0}", user.LastName)</div>
    <div>@string.Format("Status: {0}", user.Status.Humanize())</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
    <div>---</div>
</li>
}
```

Note that the content is wrapped in an

. The reason for this is because the parent container (_containerId HTML object) is a . But we can always change this implementation very easily, as long as we maintain the hierarchy as below:

```
<parentContainer>
  <childContainer>
     [Content]
  </childContainer>
</parentContainer>
```

This is because RustyLazyLoad control uses the parent container's number of children to update the _fromRowNumber property, which ensures there is no duplicate entry in the next load.

The above code is not written by me. But i have successfully used in my project. the reference is taken from the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624529/RustyLazyLoad?fid=1837489&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&tid=4718865) where you have the complete description. All credits to [Teddy Segoro](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624529/RustyLazyLoad?fid=1837489&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&tid=4718865) . I have reposted it only for an information sharing. You can find the working model as

[image: 1st image]

[image: 2nd image]

[image: 3rd image]

Comment: A huge thanks for the efforts. I will try this out. Also will put this as answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet but will be looking for a similar soultion soon: The term is called "lazy loading"

http://dcarrith.github.io/jquery.mobile.lazyloader/