# Show more data on click using mvc and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have list of 500 of data on page without paging, i want to use scrolling or button click to show load data on the same page without a postback.

when page loads for the first time it will take 500 data but show only 100 data and when user click on button it will show next 100 and so on.

My project on mvc 4

Comment: Please refer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041940/load-data-only-when-page-is-scrolled-down-mvc-4-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below displays 3 items at a time.If you would like to change it to another value e.g. 100 just set the `pageSize` variable in the view to the desired value.I hope the example below helps you and please remember to mark as answered:

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetAlotOfUsers()
    {
        var employees = new List<object>();

        employees.Add(new { Name = "Name 1", Surname = "Surname 1" });
        employees.Add(new { Name = "Name 2", Surname = "Surname 2" });
        employees.Add(new { Name = "Name 3", Surname = "Surname 3" });
        employees.Add(new { Name = "Name 4", Surname = "Surname 4" });
        employees.Add(new { Name = "Name 5", Surname = "Surname 5" });
        employees.Add(new { Name = "Name 6", Surname = "Surname 6" });
        employees.Add(new { Name = "Name 7", Surname = "Surname 7" });
        employees.Add(new { Name = "Name 8", Surname = "Surname 8" });
        employees.Add(new { Name = "Name 9", Surname = "Surname 9" });
        employees.Add(new { Name = "Name 10", Surname = "Surname 10" });

        return Json(employees, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var employees = null;
        var page = 1;
        var pageSize = 3;

        $("#getEmployees").click(function () {
            $("#results").empty();

            $.getJSON("/Home/GetAlotOfUsers", function (data) {
                employees = data;

                for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
                    if (i < pageSize) {
                        $("#results").append("<div>" + employees[i].Name + " " + employees[i].Surname + "</div>");
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
            });
        });

        $("#previous").click(function () {
            if (employees != null && page > 1) {
                $("#results").empty();

                for (var i = ((page - 2) * pageSize) ; i < employees.length; i++) {
                    if (i < ((page - 1) * pageSize)) {
                        $("#results").append("<div>" + employees[i].Name + " " + employees[i].Surname + "</div>");
                    }
                }
                page--;
            }
        });

        $("#next").click(function () {
            if (employees != null && (page * pageSize) < employees.length) {
                $("#results").empty();

                for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
                    if (i >= (page * pageSize) && i < ((page + 1) * pageSize)) {
                        $("#results").append("<div>" + employees[i].Name + " " + employees[i].Surname + "</div>");
                    }
                }
                page++;
            }
        });
    })
</script>

<input type="button" value="GetEmployees" id="getEmployees" />

<div id="results">

</div>
<input type="button" id="previous" value="Previous" />
<input type="button" id="next" value="Next" />
```